# Angular Js submit doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular Js submit doesn't seem to be working
It loads and it doesn't give me any errors, but the posts are not being added to the "posts" collection.
I'm using chrome and web server extension for chrome.

```js
angular.module('littleTweet', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider
 .state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  controller: 'MainController'
 })
 .state('posts', {
   url: '/posts/{id}',
   templateUrl: 'posts.html',
   controller: 'PostsCtrl'
 });

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

}])
.factory('posts', [function() {
 var o = { posts: []};
 return o;
}])
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts){
  $scope.posts = posts.posts;
  
  $scope.current_user = 'me';
   
   $scope.addPost = function() {
    //if(!$scope.message || $scope.message === '') { return; }
    
    $scope.posts.push({
     user: $scope.current_user,
     message: $scope.message, 
     time: new Date()
    });

  $scope.message = '';
 };
}])
.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'posts', function($scope, $stateParams, posts) {
 $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
}]);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Little Tweet</title>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="littleTweet">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   
   <ui-view></ui-view>
      
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Little Tweet</h1>
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">

          {{post.user}}: {{post.message}} at {{post.time}}
        </span>
      </div>

      <form ng-submit="addPost()"
        style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Message"
            ng-model="message"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
   <div class="page-header">
     <h1>Little tweet</h1>
   </div>

   <!-- rest of template -->
 </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form aren't related to MainController. This are outside of the ui-view.

Comment: Can you produce a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Shaohao, the fiddle is in the post already.

Comment: You missed `ng-controller="MainController"` in the HTML

Comment: Gonzalo, shouldn't the route take care of that? I tried putting:
      <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">

          {{post.user}}: {{post.message}} at {{post.time}}
        </span>
      </div>
Inside the home.html and it didn't work either.

But indeed, if I make the controller explicit it works.

Comment: You would need to also put the form inside home.html for that to work, because it uses the controller as well